# graphql supertest , error message: 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation

Tags: graphql, integration-testing, supertest

consider this simple resolver for user creation and update:

```
@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolver {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Mutation(() => User)
  async CreateUser(@Args('payload') payload: CreateUserInput) {
    return this.userService.createUser(payload);
  }

  @Mutation(() => User)
  async UpdateUser(@Args('payload') payload: UpdateUserInput) {
    return this.userService.updateUser(payload);
  }
```

when I create and update using grapqhl playground, it works nice :

[image: correct form] 
In running tests, the same query is ok for creation(as logged in the image) but has error with update mutation which is same in both queries:

```
export const UpdateUserMutation = `
mutation UpdateUser( $id:String!, $email:String ) {
  UpdateUser(payload: { _id: $id, email: $email }) {
    _id
    phone
    email
  }
}
`;
```

[image: error messaage]

so am i missing somthing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my tests, I was using `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to reset the DB and the server.
by using `beforeAll` and `afterAll`
the created user were kept so that user was updated successfully.